# React history push data as parameter to page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router

I have an Ionic React application where `history.replace` is used to redirect the user from the settings page to the login screen when they click a logout button. I want to be able to pass a `loggedOut` flag in the redirection. Then on the Login page, I can check if the `loggedOut` flag is set and display a "You are logged out" toast message.

This is the settings page code with a Logout button

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from "react-router";

interface PageProps {
    pageName: string | undefined;
}

const SettingsTab: React.FC<PageProps> = ({ pageName }) => {
    console.log("render TabPage " + pageName);

    const history = useHistory();

    return (
      <IonPage>
        <IonHeader>
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonButtons slot="start">
              <IonMenuButton />
            </IonButtons>
            <IonTitle>{pageName}</IonTitle>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>
        <IonContent>
        <IonButton
          onClick={async () => {
            await logOut();
            history.replace("/login");
            //history.replace("/login", {loggedOut : "yes"});
          }}
        >
          LOGOUT
        </IonButton>
        </IonContent>
      </IonPage>
    );
};
```

The Login page:

```
import React from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router";

const Login: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ history }) => {
  // Check if loggedOut is set so we can display "You are logged out" message

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonButtons slot="start">
            <IonMenuButton />
          </IonButtons>
          <IonTitle>Login Page {""}</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>

      <IonContent>
        <IonButton
          onClick={async () => {
            await logIn();
            history.replace("/dashboard");
          }}
        >
          LOGIN
        </IonButton>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};
```

I am still a new user of React so I appreciate any help or advice on this problem.

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` in order to store and verify the auth state of the user, for example:

```js
<IonButton
  onClick={async () => {
    await logIn();
    localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", true);
    history.replace("/dashboard");
  }}
>
  LOGIN
</IonButton>;
```

then:

```
<IonButton
  onClick={async () => {
    await logOut();
    localStorage.removeItem("isLoggedIn");
    history.replace("/login");
  }}
>
  LOGOUT
</IonButton>;
```

To check if user is logged in:

```js
const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn") // returns true or false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate to the login page while passing your state(flag) like this

```
history.replace("/login", {loggedOut : true});
```

then in the login component you can access the state value like this:
**EDITED**

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

// A simple component that shows the pathname of the current location
class Login extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props;
    const isLoggedOut = location.state && location.state.loggedOut 

    return (
          <div>
               <div>You are now at {location.pathname}</div>
               {isLoggedOut ? <p>You have loggedout</p> : ''}
          </div>;
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

Comment: How would I modify the Login page code to support this? I get a "Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'" on the "history.location.state.loggedOut" line.

Comment: @StephenGlass You can access the history object in the component using the withRouter HOC. See more here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter